# Paging SQL Server results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Orders` and `Articles`. I want both `orders` and `articles` in the same result set, sorted by `[DateCreated]`. I need paging, so I am using WITH. The problem with the query below, is that `[RowNumber]` is a separate counter for each of the queries.

Instead of getting 10 rows in the following query, I get 20. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

I need a counter that encompasses the whole WITH clause.

Query:

```
;WITH MySelectedRows AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateCreated] DESC) as [RowNumber]
    , [ArticleID]     as [ID]
    , [DateCreated]   as [Date]
    , [ArticleText]   as [Text]
    , 'Articles'      as [RowType]
    FROM Articles

    UNION

    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DateCreated] DESC) as [RowNumber]
    , [OrderID]       as [ID]
    , [DateCreated]   as [Date]
    , [OrderText]     as [Text]
    , 'Orders'        as [RowType]
    FROM Orders
)
SELECT [ID], [Date], [Text], [RowType] FROM MySelectedRows
WHERE [RowNumber] BETWEEN 1 and 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the row number on the combined result set, not on each of the 2 queries. Therefore, you can wrap the union in a CTE/subquery, then apply `ROW_NUMBER` and do the paging, like so:

```
;with cte as
(
 SELECT
, [ArticleID]     as [ID]
, [DateCreated]   as [Date]
, [ArticleText]   as [Text]
, 'Articles'      as [RowType]
FROM Articles

UNION

SELECT
, [OrderID]       as [ID]
, [DateCreated]   as [Date]
, [OrderText]     as [Text]
, 'Orders'        as [RowType]
FROM Orders
),

ordered as
(
 select
 *
 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) as [RowNumber]
from cte
)

select * from ordered
where RowNumber between 1 and 10
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks will try this.

Comment: @PålThingbø No problems. Please check my edit, had a syntax error earlier.